How to convert values from columns to rows



Order ID
Customer Name
Email Address
Product 1 - Brand
Product 1 - Description
Product 1 - Price
Product 2 - Brand
Product 2 - Description
Product 2 - Price




123
John Smith
johnsmith@gmail.com
Carrier
Inverter Airconditioning Unit
599
null
null
null


456
Jane Smith
j.smith@icloud.com
Lenovo
ThinkVision Monitor
149
Logitech
Ergonomic Mouse
79



I'm working with this kind of table/dataset that keeps a record of a customer's purchases but all of the products they bought are contained within a single row.
The table has 10 sets of these product brand, product description, product price, etc but what I would like to happen is to take the individual purchases from that single row and create subsequent rows with the details of the remaining products while still having the info of the customers.
There would be instances where a customer would only get one item so the rest of the columns would be empty. There are also other columns at the end of the table that has the total cost of their items, delivery address, etc that I also want to retain in the new rows that would be created.
What I want to achieve is something like this:



Order ID
Customer ID
Email Address
Product - Brand
Product - Description
Product - Price




123
John Smith
johnsmith@gmail.com
Carrier
Inverter Airconditioning Unit
599


456
Jane Smith
j.smith@icloud.com
Lenovo
ThinkVision Monitor
149


456
Jane Smith
j.smith@icloud.com
Logitech
Ergonomic Mouse
79



I'm uncertain how to go about this as this seems complicated. I know there's a similar function in Google Sheet where you transpose the cells but that only solves half of my problem. Any help/recommendation would be highly appreciated, thank you!

You can use multicolumn UNPIVOT operation in BigQuery.
For multicolumn unpivot we use form
UNPIVOT (multi_column_unpivot) [unpivot_alias]  

There multi_column_unpivot is
    values_column_set
    FOR name_column
    IN (column_sets_to_unpivot)

values_column_set-> (brand,description,price)
column_sets_to_unpivot -> (brand1,description1,price1) ,(brand2,description2, price2),(brand3 ...)
You should include to this list all your table triples(brandN,descriptionN,priceN)
See example
with data as(
select 123 OrderID,'John Smith' as CustomerName,    'johnsmith@gmail.com' as EmailAddress,  'Carrier'  as Brand1, 'Inverter Airconditioning Unit' description1,599 price1   
    ,cast(null as string) Brand2,   cast(null as string) Description2,cast(null as integer) price2
  union all
select 456 OrderId, 'Jane Smith'CustomerName,   'j.smith@icloud.com' EmailAddress,'Lenovo' brand1,  'ThinkVision Monitor' description1, 149 price1
          , 'Logitech' brand2,  'Ergonomic Mouse' Description2, 79 price2

)
-- query
select OrderID, CustomerName, EmailAddress
  ,brand, description, price
from data
unpivot( (brand,description,price)  
       for col  in( (brand1,description1,price1) 
                   ,(brand2,description2,price2)
                  ) 
       )upvt;




Row
OrderID
CustomerName
EmailAddress
brand
description
price




1
123
John Smith
johnsmith@gmail.com
Carrier
Inverter Airconditioning Unit
599


2
456
Jane Smith
j.smith@icloud.com
Lenovo
ThinkVision Monitor
149


3
456
Jane Smith
j.smith@icloud.com
Logitech
Ergonomic Mouse
79




Thank you! This helped me get the data that I need, appreciate your help so much!

You can use UNION ALL to combine the result set from multiple queries.
I dont have big query so was unable to test, but syntax should be fairly same for big query.
Fiddle
SELECT 
    OrderID,
    CustomerName,
    EmailAddress,
    Product1_Brand AS Product_Brand,
    Product1_Description AS Product_Description,
    Product1_Price AS Product_Price
FROM CustomerPurchases
WHERE Product1_Brand IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    OrderID,
    CustomerName,
    EmailAddress,
    Product2_Brand AS Product_Brand,
    Product2_Description AS Product_Description,
    Product2_Price AS Product_Price
FROM CustomerPurchases
WHERE Product2_Brand IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY OrderID;

Output


Thanks for your input! The UNION ALL statement wasn't really what I was looking for but this helped me understand BigQuery more, appreciate your help!
